# command `npm install npm@5.5.1 -g` failed

Tags: npm, npm-install

I want to upgrade npm by command`npm install npm@5.5.1 -g`.It did success,but command `npm -v` still show older version.
How could I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Take a new terminal tab and try.

Comment: @HarikrishnanThe result is the same.

Comment: what is the ouput of `which npm`

Comment: @Harikrishnan I am using  Win10 OS.The command ``npm -v`` in cmd shows '3.10.10',but `5.5.1` in git bash.I do not know why.

Comment: I think the path is different. Check this and set corect path for npm. https://superuser.com/a/949577/181550

Answer (score 0):

You probably have 2 version of NPM installed on your computer now.
I suggest to find the older one and remove it you can try with instructions from the official site [HERE](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/removing-npm.html)

If after deleting the older version you cant find NPM on windows bash add NPM folder to your path